# Deleting rows in a dataset when they are missing data in a specific column using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to identify which rows have a value of `nan` in a specific column (index 2), and either delete the rows that have `nan` or move the ones that don't have `nan` into their own dataframe. Any recommendations on how to go about either way?

I've tried to create a vector with all of the rows and specified column, but the data type object is giving me trouble. Also, I tried creating a list and adding all of the rows that `!= 'nan'` in that specific column to the list.

```
patientsDD = patients.iloc[:,2].values

ddates = []
for value in patients[:,2]:
    if value != 'nan':
        ddates.append(value)
```

I'm expecting that it returns all of the rows that `!= 'nan'` in index 2, but nothing is added to the list, and the error I am receiving is `'(slice(None, None, None), 2)' is an invalid key`.

I'm a newbie to all of this, so I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (assuming df is the name of your data frame):

```
import numpy as np
df1 = df[np.isfinite(df['index 2'])]
```

This will give you a new data frame df1 with only the rows that have a finite value in the column index 2. You can also try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = df[pd.notnull(df['index 2'])]
```

If you want to drop all the rows that have NaN values in any of the columns, you can use this:

```
df1 = df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isna()` of pandas:

```
patients[!patients.iloc[:, 2].isna()]
```

Instead of delete rows are `nan`, you can select only rows that are not `nan`.